# Поиск пути к контроллеру ASP.NET Web Api на Apache

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, asp.net-web-api, mono

Создал приложение ASP.NET Web Api для парсинга входящих данных, их обработки, фильтрации, и отправки их на другой сервер. HTML страница не нужна. 
Приложение скопилировано при помощи Mono на Linux и запущено на Apache
Какой адрес в строке запросса браузера надо ввести чтобы попасть на нужный контроллер?

Comment: Это определяется в вашем роутинге. У вас атрибут-роутинги?

Comment: Нет. Не знаю как их правильно настроить

Comment: Если вы ничего не меняли в стандартном роутинге - тогда пишите в браузере `http://localhost:port/Controller/Action` и всё. Под именем контроллера понимается имя без слова Controller. Порт можно посмотреть в настройках apache - либо там где директива Listen, либо если используете виртуалхосты - то в настройках конкретного виртуального хоста. Также возможно ваше приложение собирали со swagger - можете попробовать зайти на `http://localhost:port/swagger` и поиграться с запросами. Я с версией под mono дел не имел, поэтому возможно что-то неприменимо к вашей ситуации.